# Override TextBlock style of ContentPresenter in Metro theme

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I use metro theme in my project.

I have a style for TextBlock Base.

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockText" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF63798F"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```

I want to change the foreground of GridViewColumnHeader by setting a style for it. I added `TextBlock.Foreground="White"` for  `ContentPresenter` of it. But it doesn't change color!

When I remove the TextBlock style it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `Foreground` property of `TextBlockText`
2. add a style for `Windows`
3. Add `TextBlock.Foreground='White'` for ContentPresenter .